# Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc

Tags: android

Does anyone know why this error will be? I have been looking for but I did not find anything that could help me, any one could guide me please :

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toLowerCase(java.util.Locale)' on a null object reference at blm.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@16078052@16.0.78 (040700-233153861):66) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: It's a common NullPointerException, you get NullPointerException when you try to use the object when it is not initialized, or the object is null when you tried to operate on it.

Answer (score -1):

Add a null check on the string. Looks like a common error